# javascript add minutes to new Date(); before using the object

Tags: javascript, date, dateadd

I have a function calls that start a bunch of timers and I want to add a few minutes to each one so they don't all start off at zero.  I had success with:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var twentyMinutesLater = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (20 * 60 * 1000));
new CountUp(twentyMinutesLater, 'counter03');
```

I would love to skip creating the var twentyMinutesLater and so on for all the timers I want, I just can't get the syntax right, or maybe it's not possible.  Is there a way to add the milliseconds that in the function call below.

```
new CountUp(new Date(), 'counter03');
```

I've tried:

```
new CountUp((new Date() + (20 * 60 * 1000)), 'counter03');
```

Result NaN NaN:NaN:NaN so it's not a number
Same result with double quotes.

Any javascript syntax masters out there that have any ideas?

Comment: Well, the two statements are not the same. You've done something different in your example without `twentyMinutesLater`. Look at the syntax again.

Comment: This exact answer with a working jsFiddle demo was already provided to your previous question here (by me): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8887920/816620

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript count up timer modification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887510/javascript-count-up-timer-modification).  In the future, please edit your previous question to clarify rather than post a new question that is nearly identical.

Comment: thanks jfriend.  the fiddle page is awesome. Now to find my syntax error.  It is a bit of a duplicate, but it seemed to me specific enough to start a new question.  Should I delete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific code, you're passing a Date object to the counter code and that is not what it is expected.  It is expecting a time value from which it will make it's own Date object (you can see that right in the constructor for the Counter function).  Plus, the counter code won't take times in the future, only times in the past (perhaps because it doens't want to deal with negative times - I don't know).

Here's a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/NshSf/10/) where I've modified my other jsFiddle used in the answer to your other question.

```
function addCounter() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var twentyMinutesLater = currentDate.getTime() - (20 * 60 * 1000);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = "counter" + counterNum++;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    new CountUp(twentyMinutesLater, div.id);
}
```

And, here's a jsFiddle that lets you enter a number of minutes and it will start a counter at that value: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vnf5z/.

Comment: Added a new jsFiddle that lets you set the initial time delta for the counter.

Comment: Thank you again!  Your last answer was so complete that it answered a question I didn't even know I was going to have yet.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should do:

```
var d = new Date();
new CountUp(d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 20), 'counter03');
```

Depending on how the CountUp constructor uses the date object passed to it, and whether you want to re-use *d*, you might need:

```
var d = new Date();
new CountUp(new Date(d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 20)), 'counter03');
```

so that each call to *CountUp* gets a different date object.

Answer (score 0):

new Date() does return an object not the timestamp, so you should'nt use a mathematical operation there(at least no addition, when you expect a Number as result). 
Use Date.getTime() :

```
//when you need a Date-object as argument
  new CountUp(new Date(new Date().getTime() + (20 * 60 * 1000)) , 'counter03');
//when you need the timestamp as argument
  new CountUp((new Date().getTime() + (20 * 60 * 1000)) , 'counter03');
```

See the fiddle to recognize the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8v4Tx/

Comment: If you look at the counter code, it does not expect a Date Object to be sent to it.  It expects a number of milliseconds from the master date.  So your double new Date constructor is not required at all.

Comment: It may expect a number(it's not clear, I don't see the contents of CountUp() anywhere), but check the the type, it's a string! The representation may be the same, but the result when using this as parameter for new Date() is completely different....as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8v4Tx/

Comment: The code for CountUp is in the [dup previous question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887510/javascript-count-up-timer-modification) that I had already answered.  The first line of `CountUp()` is this: `this.beginDate = new Date(initDate);` where initDate is the first argument to the constructor.  It certainly doesn't need a date object.  It will take anything that a Date object constructor will take and milliseconds from epoch works just fine.

Comment: Yes, and if the provided argument is a string instead of a number (happens when you use an addition  with the Date-object) shit happens. That's what I'm talkin about, and that's the issue in the OP's try `(new Date() + (20 * 60 * 1000)`

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now. I didn't notice that the OP was doing it that way in the third block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach that I've seen been used in Rails. You'd create relative date objects using this syntax,

```
(20).minutes().fromNow()
```

Or, if you hate the noise from the parentheses, you could do this (only on ES5 compatible browsers),

```
(20).minutes.fromNow
```

Here's the first non-ES5 solution that adds methods on the Number prototype.

```
Number.prototype.minutes = function() {
    // minutes to milliseconds
    return this * 60 * 1000;
};

Number.prototype.fromNow = function() {
    var futureDate = new Date(Date.now() + this);
    return futureDate;
};
```

[`new CountUp((20).minutes().fromNow(), 'foo')`](http://jsfiddle.net/q48rF/)

Here's the ES5 solution that adds function backed properties.

```
Object.defineProperties(Number.prototype, {
    minutes: {
        get: function() {
            // minutes to milliseconds
            return this * 60 * 1000;
        }
    },
    fromNow: {
        get: function() {
            var futureDate = new Date(Date.now() + this);
            return futureDate;
        }
    }
});
```

[`new CountUp((20).minutes.fromNow, 'foo')`](http://jsfiddle.net/VUKQ4/)

There are different schools of thought on extending of native objects. One group forbids it at any cost, while the other encourage using it almost everywhere. As with anything, striking a balance is important.

Comment: Extending native objects is fine, it's extending **built-in** objects that should only be done after careful consideration.